# Laravel 5.5 upgrade from 5.4 getting error

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to upgrade laravel 5.4 to 5.5
i have been following the upgrade guide of laravel

I use "composer update", I get the following error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.42
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41....

     - tymon/jwt-auth 1.0.0-beta.3 requires illuminate/support 
5.1.* || 5.2.* ||5.3.* || 5.4.* -> satisfiable by lavel/framework[v5.4.36], illuminate/support[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9]. - tymon/jwt-auth 1.0.0-beta.3 requires illuminate/support 5.1.* || 5.2.* ||
5.3.* || 5.4.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.4.36], lluminate/support[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9].    - don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.3.0    

- don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0|don't install illuminate/support v5.3.16....

- Installation request for laravel

 /framework 5.5.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.0, v5.5.1, v5.5.10, v5.5.11, v5.5.12, v5.5.13, v5.5.14, v5.5.15, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.18, v5.5.19, v5.5.2, v5.5.20, v5.5.21, v5.5.22, v5.5.23, v5.5.24, v5.5.25, v5.5.26, v5.5.27, v5.5.28, v5.5.29, v5.5.3, v5.5.30, v5.5.31, v5.5.32, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.38, v5.5.39, v5.5.4, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.42, v5.5.5, v5.5.6, v5.5.7, v5.5.8, v5.5.9].
- Installation request for tymon/jwt-auth 1.0.0-beta.3 -> satisfiable by tymon/jwt-auth[1.0.0-beta.3].
```

is there any solution for this error.

i am using php 7.0.29

my **composer.json**

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.11.0",
    "bosnadev/repositories": "0.*",
    "braintree/braintree_php": "^3.35",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "kreait/firebase-php": "^4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "lcobucci/jwt": "^3.2",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
    "setasign/fpdf": "^1.8",
    "setasign/fpdi": "^2.0",
    "smalot/pdfparser": "*",
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "1.0.0-beta.3",
    "webpatser/laravel-uuid": "^3.0"

},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",

    "filp/whoops": "~2.0"
},
```

Comment: Please do not add code in comments. Edit your question instead, because only there you could format code as code. Code in comments is just not readable in most cases.

Comment: did u find solution?

Comment: you have packages that conflict .. there are packages that require versions of illuminate packages that are lower than the ones you want to end up installing ... specifically `tymon/jwt-auth` as composer is telling you exactly why it wont install the new version of laravel

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to install Laravel 5.5 separately and then migrate your code inside newly installed laravel project.

**Note:** do this only if you haven't changed any vendor files.

Comment: i have change "tymon/jwt-auth": "1.0.0-beta.3" instead of "tymon/jwt-auth": "1.0.0-rc.1". now its updated.

Comment: congrats brother :)